# jQuery get id by .event function

Tags: jquery

```
var e = jQuery.Event("onmouseover");
e.attr("id");
```

I want to get id of this element but it does not work. `e` returns object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `jQuery.Event`, which creates a new event object to be passed around to the elements, does what you want.

I think you only want to get the ID of certain elements when the mouse passes over them? If so, and the elements have a common class name, then do:

```
$('.someClassName').mouseover() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

If they are all of the same tag, e.g. `<p>`, then do something like:

```
$('tag').mouseover() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

If you want to do this for *all* elements on the page (not recommended, usually you can narrow it down):

```
$(document).delegate('*', 'mouseover', function (e) {
   if (this == e.target) alert(this.id);
});
```

You may want to read more about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get to the elements that you want.

Comment: @senza, that would be the same, but replace `.click` with `.mouseover`. I've modified my answer to show this.